# How to use TEdgeComponent with oficial release of Microsoft Edge

Tags: microsoft-edge, delphi-10.4-sydney, tedgebrowser

Is it possible to use the Delphi 10.4 TEdgeComponent with the official release of Microsoft Edge and WebView2 insted of the Edge Canary channel?

I have installed the oficial release of edge with the latest WebView2 avaiable here
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.WebView2 and it didn´t work.

The only way I was able to get the sample project to work, was by installing the canary channel version.
Which is not a problem talking about the development environment.

But to force the end users to install the canary channel version, is not a good approach.

How to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need Delphi 10.4.2. See this [Embarcadero video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M3e7X1cplgw).

Also have a look at this [Embarcadero blog post](https://blogs.embarcadero.com/execute-scripts-and-view-source-with-tedgebrowser/). It explain how to install the required dependencies.

And this [source code](https://github.com/Embarcadero/RADStudio-DemoKit/tree/main/10.4.2-demos/EdgeView).

Comment: Yes, i´m using 10.4.2, but the only way to get the sample avaiable at demo folder, was installing the Microsoft Edge Canary Channel.

Comment: Did you had a look at the video?

Comment: Yes, it does not contains any usefull info.

Comment: Here is the official Embarcadero Docummentation:  http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Using_TEdgeBrowser_Component_and_Changes_to_the_TWebBrowser_Component . As you can see, it states that Canarium channel should be installed.  But I´m not sure if the official docummentation is outdated, because it states that there is no production version of webview2 avaiable.  I was able to make it work using the latest webview2 and the edge canary channel, but the question has to do with the oficial release of Edge with the TEdgeBrowser component.

Comment: Was you able to make it work with the official release of Edge?

Comment: You still have to deploy the dependencies (EdgeView2 runtime by Microsoft). Read the blog post I gave the link.

Comment: You are right. Will test this in a bit.  Thank you.